# Disable hibernate 6.1.5.Final from logging envers-generated HBM mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Attempted:**

Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.5 to 3.0.0, which uses Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final

**Issue:**

After upgrade, hibernate logs XML of envers-generated HBM mapping in logs as below,

```
2023-03-07T16:50:59.558-05:00 DEBUG 27508 --- [           main] ca.dev.cicd.DbTestApp                    : Running with Spring Boot v3.0.0, Spring v6.0.2
...
2023-03-07T16:51:03.206-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
2023-03-07T16:51:03.464-05:00  WARN 27508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-03-07T16:51:04.226-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2023-03-07T16:51:04.373-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2023-03-07T16:51:05.231-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: [class-names]
2023-03-07T16:51:05.243-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] .e.b.i.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl : Adding JAXB document mapping
2023-03-07T16:51:05.600-05:00  INFO 27508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.envers.boot                : HHH90005601: Envers-generated HBM mapping...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false" xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm">
   <class>
      ...
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Question:**

How to prevent/disable the envers-generated XML from being logged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the logs of this class configuring your application.

application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.envers.boot = OFF
```

application.yml:

```
logging:
    level:
        org.hibernate.envers.boot: OFF
```

Comment: Thank you. That disabled the XML from logging.